# How to use Jquery Datatables.net (and all its features) in meteor

Tags: meteor, datatables

I'm working on moving some projects to meteor that are currently using jquery datables and most of the plugins offered by jquery datatables.net.

The main project I've found that can help with this is [meteor-tabular](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-tabular) which appears to no longer be maintained.

How do you use jquery datatables and all its plugins inside meteor without using tabular?

Comment: Tabular is your best bet, it is running in production for us on 1.3.1. It looks like it might be forked soon as well: https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-tabular/issues/345